# How specific should my database schemas be?

Tags: mongodb, performance, meteor, database

I'm using MongoDB as a datastore with MeteorJS. I want to know how detailed should my schema be for every document. Example:

```
subscriberIds: {
    type: Array,
    defaultValue: []
},
totalSubscribers: {
    type: Number,
    defaultValue: 0
}
```

I have a choice whether just use subscriberIds.length() or just retrieve totalSubscribers but I don't know what would be the better option from an efficiency stand point.

Comment: What's the use case? If the array is extremely large, you may as well just retrieve totalSubscribers. However, I'm pretty sure either would work fine.

Comment: You should probably add `totalSubscribers` only if you need that information in a publish function. For example, if you want to find all documents where `totalSubscribers` > 10.

Comment: I agree with both of these.  Agrigating values makes sense only if there is a lot of data to process OR it makes some other aspect of the code easier.  Otherwise, you will be constantly updating and maintaining the agrigate data, and could run into problems if bugs caused the data to get out of sync.